# Can't Find Option to Create Feature Layer

Tags: arcgis

I have an ArcGIS online account, but I can't find option to create a feature layer.

I tried to create developers account, but yet didn't find a way to create feature layer service.

I have added data from CSV file, but don't find publish button so that it can be hosted using feature layer. How do I host my service as a feature layer?

Comment: I think this question would be much more on-topic at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: so where someone can answer it?

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) three ways to do this.

---

1. Create a feature layer when uploading data. Per [Esri help](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/publish-features.htm): When you are uploading the CSV to AGOL initially, you need to indicate that you want it also published as a feature layer:

   > **Check the box next to Publish this file as a hosted layer.**
   >
   > If you leave the box unchecked, your data file is added to My Content,
   >   but no hosted feature layer is published. You can publish the feature
   >   layer later if you want. See Add items for more information.

   [image]

---

2. Create a feature layer from already uploaded data, using the Create menu (when you're in your My Content page).

   [image]

---

3. Click "Publish" from the item's specific page.

   [image]

Comment: I didn't find any checkbox while uploading csv file

Comment: @EngrUmair I've added a screenshot.

Comment: I think you may be using arcgis desktop but I am using arcgis online

Comment: No, all these menus and screenshots are from ArcGIS Online.

Comment: I don't find any feature layer in my account.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that in your question. All the methods I've described are ways to create a feature layer from something that is not a feature layer. Did you try one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143573/discussion-between-engr-umair-and-erica).

Comment: Erica I have been trying so many things, from one post I found that there should administration role to create feature layer

Answer (score 0):

I have signed up for developers account, but didn't complete so that's why I was allocated public account rather than developers, so I created new developers account and used that account to login on [arcgis](http://www.arcgis.com/home/index.html).

Now I found the option to create feature layer, also found publish button,